# OAuth 2.0 resource server custom error format

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

The OAuth 2.0 [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) is very clear on the errors returned by the authorization server in [Section 5.2. Error Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2) :

> - **error** : REQUIRED.

- **error_description** : OPTIONAL
- **error_uri** : OPTIONAL

> [...]
>
> The parameters are included in the entity-body of the HTTP response
> using the "application/json" media type as defined by [RFC4627].

A sample HTTP response is even provided :

```
 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "error":"invalid_request"
 }
```

When it comes to the resource server (the protected HTTP resources), the RFC is vague about this part in [Section 7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-7.2) :

> If a resource access request fails, the resource server SHOULD inform
> the client of the error.
> While the specifics of such error responses
> are beyond the scope of this specification, this document establishes
> a common registry in Section...

One may already have its custom error response "data structure" in place.
Implementations like spring-security-oauth2 use the same error format for the authorization server and resource server by default.

This default behavior would lead API clients to process two different data structures for authorization errors and business errors, which is highly inconvenient.

On the other hand, I find it really weird to mold an HTTP API's errors based on the authorization framework : especially when we use multiple types of authorization/authentication for the same resources.

At this point I find it more appealing to have the same user-defined error structure for all resource server errors, including OAuth-related authorization errors like "invalid_token".

ex :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code":"1001"
    "type":"invalid_token"
    "message":"Expired access token"
  }
  ...
}
```

***Question :*** is it a "bad"/uncommon practice to define our own error response format for the resource server ? Any elements I may forget to consider ?

The idea is to be as user-friendly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the interface between Client and Authorization Server is well defined is because of interoperability. Clients should be able to work with (more or less) arbitrary Authorization Servers.

On the other hand, the interface between Clients and Resource Servers is less well defined. This is because a Client is inherently more tightly bound to the Resource Server because it needs to understand the API specific semantics and syntax of the API anyway before it can do something useful with it. The semantics and syntax extend itself to the error handling for the API.

But if you control both Resource Server and Client it may make sense from a developer point of view to adopt the same approach as done for OAuth 2.0 as to make error handling more uniform for the client. That's not uncommon and certainly not bad practice. It is really up to you (i.e. Resource Server implementer).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, sounds very logic. `But if you control both Resource Server and Client` : do you mean Resource Server and Authorization Server ?

Comment: no; I meant to say that the interaction between Resource Server and Client is very specific and it is easier to control and modify that to your likings if you control both entities; the interface to the Authorization Server is standardized anyway and should not need to be customized even if you control both

Comment: Got it. The key argument here is that since clients will have to get into our API's details anyway, it makes a lot of sense to keep our own error format -- and fit OAuth authorizations errors in there, just like we did with HTTP basic.

Answer (score 1):

As with most Spring Security authentication errors this one is handled by an `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. By default you get an `OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint` injected into your `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` but you can add your own, either by building the filter yourself or pushing it into the `ResourceServerConfigurer` callback.

Comment: Thanks for the technical hints. I knew the default behavior could easily be extended and customized, the question was more : _is it cool/common to do it for resource server errors?_ . BTW, great job and thanks a lot for this cool framework :)

Comment: It's probably not super common because you won't get much more information from the exception than you already see in the default. All you could do is reformat it. But the extension point is there, and there's a callback to customize it, so I don't think it's unreasonable to use it.

Comment: As you said, it's just about changing the format. The resources we are protecting with OAuth already existed with HTTP basic authentication, and had their own standard for errors. The idea is to add another authorization mechanism, without forcing clients to deal with a new error format introduced by OAuth specific errors.